# button submitting form without type submit

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have this:

```
<form action="/newPost" method="POST" style="max-width:450px; margin:50px auto;">
        <a href="/media">See Current Posts</a>
          <input name="postTitle" type="text" class="f-input" placeholder="Subject">
          <input name="socialLink" type="text" class="f-input" placeholder="Social Link">
          <textarea name="postDescription" class="f-input" placeholder="Type a message"></textarea>
          <input type="text" name="url" id="url" required readonly>
          <button id="upload_widget" class="button">Upload Photo</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" value="Send">Send</button>
      </form>
```

however, when I click this `<button id="upload_widget" class="button">Upload Photo</button>` button, It actually submits the form, however, I am not defining `type=submit`!!! It shouldn't be submitting the form unless it is submit as the type. Am i wrong? How do i fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type):

> The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state.

The default `type` of a `<button>` element is `submit`.

If you want it to only trigger JavaScript then you must *explicitly* set it to `type="button"`.

Comment: wow, didn't know this. awesome, thank you!